# How many new Monero are mined every day?

Tags: mining, bitcoin

If there are 720 blocks mined and the amount of coins that are made for each  block is 10.88, but let's just say it's 10.5 coins per block, do we not just multiply 720 by 10.5?

> 720 x 10.5 = 7560

Answer (score 1):

At time of writing, emission (new Monero) is 1.085279 per block. Block target time is 120 seconds, so that's an approximate 781 XMR per day (`1.085279 * 720`), which is constantly decreasing until it hits 0.6 XMR per block ([tail emission](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/moneropedia/tail-emission.html), ~432 per day).